# What exactly happens when calling the PayPal REST API execute URL for subscriptions

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

When using the PayPal rest API to create subscriptions (recurring payments) there are two steps to go through once the billing agreement had been created; going through the approval flow and then executing the payment.

I am trying to figure out exactly what happens at these stages so I can deal with errors. I assume that if a user has an expired card or something like that then they will be prompted to enter a valid one when going through the approval process. Is that true?

My main question, however, is what happens when calling the execute URL? Is payment actually taken here? If the user has no PayPal balance and no money in their bank account will an error response occur here, or will this happen in a later notification? I ask because I want to know whether I can set up a subscription in my service once I have called the execute URL or whether I need a notification to know that payment has actually occurred. Does the execute (or approval) URL make any checks against whether the customer can pay, has a valid card etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the approval process, the buyer must have an available funding source on their PayPal account. Any expired credit cards will not count at that time. During the Execute Payment phase, PayPal will not do any checks on the funding source unless a setup_fee is passed. If there is no setup_fee, the first attempt to charge the buyer will be on the start date and if there is an issue notification will be returned at that time.